# How to change the date format on SSAS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-2012

I have deployed an SQL Server 2012 on a Windows Server en-us.

Now my dates on Analysis services are in the American format (MM/dd/yyyy). the company is not American, therefore I would like to change it to yyyy-MM-dd or dd-MM-yyyy, how can i do it?

Everything seems to be properly configured, however, SSAS is refusing to output the dates in the desired format :(

---

On excel:

[image: American dates on Excel]

On cube browsing: 
[image: On cube brosing]

On dimension browsing:
[image]

---

Dimension seems to be properly configured on SSAS:
[image: SSAS dimension configuration]

Query on SQL Database engine:

[image: Query on sql engine]

---

SSAS properties
[image: SSAS properties]

SQL Server Database engine properties
[image: Database engine properties]

Windows server regional settings
[image: Server regional settings]

Comment: May be related this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492121.aspx)

Comment: @NagarajS i tried that yesterday. But it generates this error: Error 1 DimensionAttribute [Dim Date].[Sql Date] : The 'Date' data type is not allowed for the 'NameColumn' property; 'WChar' should be used.  0 0

Comment: Superbly presented question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A few month ago i was enduring the same problem with the date, i thought the issue was comming from SSAS but i was wrong...

So i totally changed my dimension table with a new table containing all date format, so now i can use any format that i want...

[image: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/647950/figure1.png]

You can find how to create it in this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho

Comment: Having a char column storing the formatted storing the date seems to be a nice work around.

Comment: BTW you might consider replace the Holiday null values by "NOT_HOLLIDAY" as described in the Data Warehouse Toolkit by Ralph Kimbal

Comment: Yes indeed...This is the link for creating the table + sp_procedure to populate it    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho...

Comment: @ASNAOUIAyoub You would not even have to extend your dimension table. You could use a view based on it containing this as a calculated column, or create a named calculation in the DSV. This could save some space and some additional steps in preparing the dimension table.

Answer (score 0):

I did have similar problem - checked all 3 environment DEV/UAT/PROD - no difference at all - however, DEV and UAT giving the Date in correct format (yyyy-mm-dd)- but PROD was in US format - tried everything, but still PROD showing in US format. Next, I reprocessed and deployed the cube from Visual Studio. Once it is completed i.e deployed to PROD - Date was in correct format - ie in yyyy-mm-dd.